# I can unzip on a remote machine but not on my computer

Tags: macos, bash, zip, tar, unzip

On a cluster I zipped a large (61GB, 9.2GB when zipped) directory.

```
zip -r zzDirectory Directory
```

I then `scp` the `zzDirectory` on my personal computer.

```
scp -r name@host.com:/path/to/zzDirectory.zip path/in/my/computer/zzDirectory.zip
```

And finally I unzipped it. I tried to unzip from the bash but it failed

```
warning [zzDirectory.zip]:  5544449626 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [zzDirectory.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

So I doubled click on the icon from the finder and the system started to unzip `zzDirectory.zip`. However, some files are missing and it looks like (I am not 100% sure yet) that some newline characters (`\n`) are missing as well. `unzip` used to work fine on my computer before.

In order to investigate where the problem come from, I unzipped `zzDirectory.zip` on the cluster and everything seem to work fine (no missing files).

I repeated the transfer and unzipped again but the problem persists. Note that transfers are made via internet. My OS is Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.2.

How can I solve this issue? I would prefer not to transfer data that are not zipped because of band width issue. Do you think I should try to `tar` or should I use specific options that goes with the `unzip` command line?

Comment: You used `scp` not `ftp`/`sftp` in ascii mode for the transfer? You might also want to try using `tar` and `gzip`/`bzip2`/`xz` instead of `zip` as well since that might avoid some of the potential issues here.

Comment: yes I used `scp` as indicated. The only option was `-r`. Yes I will try `tar` but it will takes a lot of time to `tar`, `scp` and "untar" (also because I don't know the `tar` commands for the moment). What are `gzip/bzip2/xz`? Are they other ways to compress data that I may want to use or are they options for the `tar` command line? Thank you!

Comment: They are other compression mechanisms, often used with `tar` (as `tar` doesn't compress). The `-z` flag for `tar` is `gzip`. The `-j` flag is `bzip2`. The `-J` flag is `xz` (relatively new so you may not have it). If you check the md5/sha1/etc. sum of the zip file on the server and on your local machine do they match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `OS X` you could try:

```
ditto -x -k the_over4gb.zip /path/to/dir/where/want/unzip
```

e.g:

```
ditto -x -k zzDirectory.zip .
```

Comment: The command line is currently running. I'll let you know when it is done. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it worked! Thanks a lot. Can you give a word to explain why it worked this time and not before. Sounds like it is linked with the size of the `.zip` file.

Comment: @Remi.b Honestly, I don't know. I'm using `ditto` for many things as an nearly universal extracting/copy-ing tool, because it preserves HFS+ extended attributes and such things... check yourself `man ditto`. I just guessed than the problem could be in 4GB limit - therefore i said: `try`. :) :) Glad to helped. :)

Comment: Ha ha Ok, fair enough. Thank you!